# Gitlab CI/CD create and use custom user functions

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I tried create like this function in my gitlab config file:

```
deploy:
  stage: dev
  services: 
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - myFunction () {   api_pl_tmp=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN_VAR" "https://git.example.ru/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines/latest" | jq .) }
    - while myFunction; do
    - if [ $(echo $api_pl_tmp | jq -r .status) = "success"  ]
    - then
    - export PROJECT_CURRENT=$($api_pl_tmp  |  jq -r '{id:.id,sha:.sha[0:8]}' | base64)
    - break
    - fi
    - if [ $(echo $api_pl_tmp | jq -r .status) = "failed"  ]
    - then
    - echo "Error: Frontend can't be deployed!"
    - exit 1
    - fi
    - if [ $(echo $api_pl_tmp | jq -r .status) = "running"  ]
    - then
    - echo "Wait 5 sec... Frontend deploying!"
    - sleep 5
    - else
    - echo Unknow status $(echo $api_pl_tmp  |  jq -r .status)
    - exit 1
    - fi
    - done
```

But it's doesn't work and gitlab return me error with message:

> This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:deploy-to-dev:script
> config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels
> deep

How I can fix this problem or maybe I have an error in my custom function?

Comment: Maybe it's possible also separate my function to `shell` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-` separates commands with commands in between. Put your commands as one command, not multiple. Remember they are joined with spaces.

The problem with your script is the colon - see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/30097 .

```
deploy:
    stage: dev
    services: 
    - docker:dind
    script:
    - "colon=:"
    - myFunction () {
        api_pl_tmp=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN$colon $TOKEN_VAR" \
        "https$colon//git.example.ru/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines/latest" | jq .);
      }
    - while myFunction; do
         if [ $(echo $api_pl_tmp | jq -r .status) = "success"  ]; then
            export PROJECT_CURRENT=$($api_pl_tmp  |  jq -r '{id:.id,sha:.sha[0:8]}' | base64);
            break;
          fi;
          if [ $(echo $api_pl_tmp | jq -r .status) = "failed"  ]; then
            echo "Error$colon Frontend cant be deployed";
            exit 1;
          fi;
          if [ $(echo $api_pl_tmp | jq -r .status) = "running"  ]; then
            echo "Wait 5 sec... Frontend deploying!";
            sleep 5;
          else
            echo Unknow status $(echo $api_pl_tmp  |  jq -r .status);
            exit 1;
          fi;
        done
```

Also `jq .) }` is missing a `;`. Check your scripts in your own shell one at a time first. Check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net .

Also `$($api_pl_tmp` is missing an echo and there are *a lot* of problem with quoting. Use consistent indentation and try to write readable code to minimize typos.

Comment: I get error `unexpected end of file (expecting "}")` @KamilCuk

Comment: `Also jq .) } is missing a ;` Please post the code first to your terminal and text. Imagine newline are replaced by spaces.